# Existence of the roots for the $x^k = a$ for $\mod n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let there is a primitive root $r$ for $\mod n$

(1) Existence of a root for the equation $x^k \equiv a \pmod n$.

Then, between the below two statements which one is the iff statement for the (1)?

Let $d = \gcd(k, \phi(n))$

1) $a^{\phi(n) \over d}\equiv 1\pmod  {\phi(n)}$

2)  $a^{\phi(n) \over d}\equiv 1\pmod  n$

---

Personally I vote to the 2nd statement is right.

Here is the ground Why I chose the 2nd statemnet.

My proof) I'm just considering the case for $gcd(n, a) = 1 $

$a^ {\phi(n) \over d}\equiv 1 (mod n)$

$\iff$ ${\phi(n) \over d} ind_r{a} \equiv 0(mod \phi(n))$for a primitive root, $r$

$\iff$ $d \vert ind_r{a}$

$\iff$ $\exists X(= ind_{r}x) \in Z$ $s.t.$ $kX \equiv ind_{r}{a}(mod \phi(n))$ for the integer set, $Z$

$\iff \exists x \in Z$ $s.t.$ $x^k \equiv a(mod n)$

But can't sure my decision is correct. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\cong a^{1/k}\pmod n$.

For some $c$, $r^c\cong a^{1/k}\pmod n$.

Now $1\cong r^{c\phi(n)}\cong a^{\phi(n)/k}\pmod n$.

Finally,  $d\mid k\implies k=f\cdot d$.  So $1\cong a^{\phi(n)/(fd)}\pmod n\implies 1^f\cong a^{\phi(n)/d}\pmod n$
or $1\cong a^{\phi(n)/d}\pmod n$.

Comment: Your proof is better than mine.